# Prevent google speech to text to convert numbers

Tags: google-cloud-speech

How to stop google speech to text convert words to numbers.
E.g. when audio contains "seven", it returns "7", but I want "seven"

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems like there's a way to boost conversion of words to numbers but not the reverse: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/class-tokens?authuser=1